# Having issues with binding names to shapes

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have created an array with Map names - 4 names and i used these names as parameters for naming rectangle shapes on a canvas. Now i would like to map these array names with the rectangle names so that when a user clicks on the rectangle, it will produce the name i have assigned.
I am trying to bind the mapNames array names to the rectangles but having trouble doing it, having issues with StringVar() and changing the values to match the different rectangles,  any help would be appreciated?

```
  class Viewer(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master = None):
    Frame.__init__(self, master)
   ........lines of code
    self.canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.bind)
    self.var = StringVar()

   def bind(self, event):
      self.x, self.y = event.x, event.y
      for names in self.mapNames:
      self.var = self.var.set(self.names) 
      return self.var

     ##Trying to set the StringVar as the names in array Mapnames so         
       that when user clicks, the Map names that is the same as the 
       names that were assigned to the rectangles will print.
```

Comment: when you do `self.var.set(...)` the return value is `None` so when you set `self.var = self.var.set(...)` you replace the reference to the StringVar to None, is it possible you just need to not assign the return value to anything?

Comment: I'm not sure naming the callback `bind` is a good idea, that means that if anything tries to do `viewer.bind("<Button-2>",seq)` for example it will fail because you have overridden the `.bind` method with something that is quite different.